# Java ArrayList adding current item to Previous item; remove current item

Tags: java, arraylist, merge, split-apply-combine

Purpose of the code is to iterate thru each item in ArrayList> listOfLists and combine previous list to current list, sort the current list and remove the next list (since already combined). This needs to happen until there is only one list left. With that I can spit out contents of ArrayList.get(0) to a file.

listOfLists was defined before code piece. 
What I am struggling with is: how can alStr1 content be sent back to listOfLists.get(0)?

```
while ( listOfLists.size() > 1 ) {
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>Iteration"+i);
    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> itr = listOfLists.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        ArrayList<String> alStr1 = itr.next();
        try{
            ArrayList<String> alStr2 = itr.next();
            alStr1.addAll(alStr2);
            Collections.sort(alStr1);
            itr.remove();
        }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any advise offered is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

```
LOGIC:
------
L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 --> L1+L2 L3+L4 L5 
L1+L2 L3+L4 L5 --> L1+L3 L5 
L1+L3 L5 --> L1+L5 
L1+L5 --> L1

L1 => going to a file.

listOfLists will include these 5 lists:
L1: [100,101,102]
L2: [200,201,202]
L3: [300,301,302]
L4: [400,401,402]
L5: [500,501,502]
Iteration 1:
L1 = L1+L2>> [100,101,102,200,201,202]
L3 = L3+L4>> [300,301,302,400,401,402]
L5 = L5   >> [500,501,502]

Iteration 2:
L1 = L1+L3>> [100,101,102,200,201,202,300,301,302,400,401,402]
L5   >> [500,501,502]

Iteration 3:
L1 = L1+L5>> [100,101,102,200,201,202,300,301,302,400,401,402,500,501,502]
```

This would explain what I am trying to achieve. Please excuse me for not adding this first.

Comment: You're not sorting the combined list - you're sorting the "next" list and then just adding it to the "current" list. But I'm not sure why you're doing it this way at all. Do you definitely need this somewhat convoluted route? Can't you just iterate over all the lists and sort + add them to the first list as you go? (Do you need `listOfLists` at all at the end, or just the single combined list?) More context would help.

Comment: @JonSkeet: For context, this is part of a sorting algorithm. I trying to implement semi merge-sort. In that, I want to breakup the dataset in multiple parts and sort each part separately, then start merging them and sorting them, over-and-over until, all the lists are merged and sorted. Merge sort would breakup the records all the way to a single element and starts merging and sorting from there.

Comment: @JonSkeet: You are right about sorting the second list and not the combined list. It should have been alStr1. Editing the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<List<Integer>> listOfList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

            Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    list.add(rand.nextInt(1000));
                }
                listOfList.add(list);
            }

            while (listOfList.size() > 1) {

                Iterator<List<Integer>> itr = listOfList.iterator();
                List<Integer> first = itr.next();

                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    List<Integer> temp = itr.next();
                    first.addAll(temp);
                    itr.remove();
                    Collections.sort(first);
                }
            }

            List<Integer> first = listOfList.get(0);
            for (Integer integer : first) {
                System.out.print(integer + ", ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will keep adding lists to the first lists. What needs to happen is, the first 2 lists merge, the next 2 will merge.. so on until the last list. Then the outer while will kickin and repeat the process until all lists are merged. 
L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 --> L1+L2 L3+L4 L5 --> L1+L3 L5 --> L1+L5 --> L1

Comment: Accepting this as the solution as, just moving the first list inside the while loop will do the trick for me. Thank you for helping me with this.
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
             first = itr.next();
             if (itr.hasNext()) {
              temp = itr.next();
              first.addAll(temp);
              itr.remove();
             }